# Group network requests with delay

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking

I have three groups of the objects are in the same Realm database. Each group is a set of tags and other information, for each tags I must make a request to the network for  receiving id. Query differs for each group (URL changes and response).

It is necessary to make requests for each group in parallel, and not more than 20 queries per minute. The program should work, even if the activity destroyed. I did IntentServie, but what should be the next step I do not know. How correctly to do parallel queries with a delay? Is it possible to do using IntentService?

Cycle "for" shown to better understand the problem. Also, all of the responses should be written in a single database, that is why access must be available to all streams.

```
public class SubscribersGathering extends IntentService {

private RealmResults<HashtagObject> hashtags;
private RealmResults<SearchtagObject> searchtags;
private RealmResults<NametagObject> nametags;

public SubscribersGathering() {
    super("SubscribersGathering");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Realm realmForThisThread = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    this.hashtags = realmForThisThread.where(HashtagObject.class).findAll();
    this.searchtags = realmForThisThread.where(SearchtagObject.class).findAll();
    this.nametags = realmForThisThread.where(NametagObject.class).findAll();
    realmForThisThread.close();

    for(int i=0;i<hashtags.size();i++){
        getHashtagTag(hashtags.get(i).getHashtag());
    }
    for(int i=0;i< searchtags.size();i++){ 
       getSearchTags(searchtags.get(i).getId());
    }
   etc     
}

private void getHashtagTag(final String tagName){

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(“URL_1”);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                String response = Tools.streamToString(urlConnection
                        .getInputStream());
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                        .nextValue();
                for(int i=0;i<jsonObj.getJSONArray("data").length();i++) {
                    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)     jsonObj.getJSONArray("data").get(i);
                    Log.d(tagName, json.getJSONObject("user").getString("id"));
                }
            }catch(Exception exc){
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(urlConnection!=null){
                    try{
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
}

  private void getSearchTags (final String tagName){

  }

   etc
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options to perform a parallel running of network operations. It's up to you what to choose. Basically, I can suggest you one of these:

1. The solution based on the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

   Split your tasks into runnables and run them using the ExecutorService. The code may look like this:

   ```
   public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         Runnable hashtagsTask = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                   for (int i = 0; i < hashtags.size(); i++) {
                        getHashtag(i);// do something, fetch hashtags, etc
                   }
              }      
         };
         Runnable searchtagsTask = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                   // do something
              }
         };


         ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
         pool.execute(hashtagsTask);
         pool.execute(searchtagsTask);
         // etc

         pool.awaitTermination();
   }
   ```
2. Split your tasks into several [IntentServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). So every service will   fetch its own data. Personally I do not think it's a good solution, but in  some cases it may be flexible.
3. Use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and its [Observable#zip](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.FuncN)) method. The key idea here will be to subscribe each observable to its own thread:

   ```
   public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         Observable.zip(
              getHashtags().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
              getSearchtags().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
              new Func2<List<String>, List<String>, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call(List<String> hashtags, List<String> searchtags) {
                          // do something with your data
                          return null;
                    }
              }
         )
         .subscribe();
    }

    private Observable<List<String>> getHashtags() {
         return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<List<String>>>() {
                   @Override
                   public Observable<List<String>> call() {
                       // fetch your data
                       return null;
                   }
         };
    }
   ```

Comment: Andrei, thank you for 3 examples. It  is  good for understanding!  The first variant for  me more preferable. But if  I start new thread  in IntentService thread can I have some problem or no? The third variant may  be good. I don't  know because I don't use  rxjava. Which variant would you choose and why?

Comment: @Delphian no, there shouldn't be any problems. Notice the line "pool.awaitTermination();". It'll make the IntentService waits until all threads will complete their execution. Personally I'd choose the 3rd option because RxJava is a powerful library. You can easily make any delays you want in fetching your data(see delay operator). Try play around with it and see if it what you're looking for. RxJava may be the pain if you don't have enough experience with it.